# Program that calculates square roots of a number.

Tags: c++

I have to make a program, which takes in a number and outputs the square root of it. Ex - 45 --> 3√5. I made a program, but it just returns the same number that i put in. Help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's my code -->

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int squarerootfinder(int number, int divisor){
     if(divisor == 1){

            return 1;
     }
     else{

            if((number / (divisor * divisor))% 1 != 0){

                    divisor = squarerootfinder(number, divisor - 1);

            }
            if((number/ (divisor * divisor)) % 1 == 0 ){
            return divisor;

            }

      }

}
int main(){
     int number;
     cout << "Enter a number to find the square root of it \n";
     cin >> number;
     int divisor = number;
     int squareroot;
     squareroot = squarerootfinder(number, divisor);
     cout << squareroot << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What attempts have you made to debug the problem?

Comment: Well, I've been reading over it for the past half hour, but I can't find where the error is. I suppose its something wrong with the function  recursion. But I'm not too sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: If you have access to a debugger, you want to walk through execution of the program, observing execution flow and the state of variables at key points in that flow. Otherwise, print to the console or a logfile to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Hint: `% 1` isn't doing what you think it's doing. Also, if it's homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! And yes, it is homework, sorry this is actually my first time posting for C++ help.

Comment: @Amadan I put in the   % 1 to see if it divided to form a whole number. If it didn't then it would subtract divisor and so on. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I see that the problem is at the if((number / (divisor * divisor))% 1 != 0) part, since that is not working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I've just realized what an idiot I am

Comment: lol... Good on you. Finding an error yourself is way more satisfying than having it given to you.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems with this line both related to the integer type:

`if((number / (divisor * divisor))% 1 != 0){`

Remembering that the result of an integer operation is an integer, what is the value of the first set of values that go into the function?  Assume `number` is 5.  Then we have:

`5/(5*5) = 5/25 = 0`

The same thing applies with the `% 1`.  ints are always whole numbers, so modding by 1 always returns 0.

Comment: rather, modulo 1 always returns zero.  It doesn't do *nothing*, it does *nothing useful*.

Comment: @BenVoigt true.  Nothing useful it is.

Answer (score -2):

The issue here is to use the right algorithm, and that is you needed to use the cmath header in std library, in your squareRootFinder function. You can also use a function to get your integer. Here is my code. Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int getPositiveInt(string rqstNum)
    {
        int num;
        do
        {
           cout << rqstNum << endl;
           cin >> num;
        }while(num == 0);

        return num;
    }


double squareRootFinder(double Num)
    {
        double squareroot;
        squareroot = sqrt(Num);
        return squareroot;
    }

int main()
{
 int Num = getPositiveInt("Enter a number and i'll calculate the squareroot ");
 double squareroot = squareRootFinder(Num);

    // To dispay the answer to two decimal places we cast the squareroot variable
    squareroot *= 100;
    squareroot = (double)((int)squareroot);
    squareroot /= 100;
    cout << squareroot << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You fixed more than you mention in your introductory paragraph.